# Docker CE on AWS GovCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Is it possible to leverage Docker in AWS GovCloud? I know that ECS is not available in that region, nor is "Docker for AWS" from what I can see.

Comment: you could always put it on your own ec2 instances..

Comment: ECS is now available in govcloud

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

[ECS is available in GovGloud as of Jan. 24th 2018](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr-are-now-available-in-aws-govcloud-us-region/).

---

Elastic Beanstalk is available in GovCloud, you can use that to [deploy a docker container](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html).

Note that you can only deploy a single container with EB in GovCloud. EB Multi-container utilizes ECS, which as you pointed out, is not available in GovCloud.